# Parsing BMP-file from mysql blob in cpp

Tags: c++, mysql, c, linux, bitmap

I need to get hold of the width and height values from the bmp so that I can pass those as arguments when I later create a gdk pixmap from the raw pixeldata in the bitmap.
I did some research on the BMP-format and the file header should look like this:

```
struct Fileheader
{
    unsigned short Type;          // signature - 'BM'
    unsigned  long Size;          // file size in bytes
    unsigned short Reserved1;     // 0
    unsigned short Reserved2;     // 0
    unsigned long  OffBits;       // offset to bitmap
    unsigned long  StructSize;    // size of this struct (40)
    unsigned long  Width;         // bmap width in pixels
    unsigned long  Height;        // bmap height in pixels
    unsigned short Planes;        // num planes - always 1
    unsigned short BitCount;      // bits per pixel
    unsigned long  Compression;   // compression flag
    unsigned long  SizeImage;     // image size in bytes
    long           XPelsPerMeter; // horz resolution
    long           YPelsPerMeter; // vert resolution
    unsigned long  ClrUsed;       // 0 -> color table size
    unsigned long  ClrImportant;  // important color count
    Fileheader()
    {
        Size=Width=Height=Planes=BitCount=Compression=SizeImage=XPelsPerMeter= YPelsPerMeter=ClrUsed=ClrImportant=Type=StructSize=Reserved1=Reserved2=OffBits=0;}
    };
}
```

after fetching the blob the standard way into row[0]

```
Fileheader fh;
memcpy(&fh, row[0], sizeof(Fileheader));
```

will give just gibberish values when

```
cout << "width: " << fh.Width << ", height: " << fh.Height << endl;
```

namely: width: 65536, height: 5626121834492592128

Anyone see what's wrong here? I'm on a 64-bit linux box BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to parse the data that way, which is discouraged, at least:

- Use correct, platform-independed types. `uint16_t` instead of `unsigned short`, `uint32_t` instead `unsigned long`
- Make your structures [packed](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Type-Attributes.html).

It won't work everywhere, but should work at least on `x86` and `x86_64`.

It's discouraged mainly because it's platform and compiler dependent:

- `__attribute__ ((packed))` is gcc extension. Other compilers may handle it differently.
- On some platforms it's impossible to tightly pack a structure. On others, they will work a little slower.
- It will work only on little-endian machines.

Answer (score 0):

The `unsigned long` values in this structure should be only 32 bits. Given the value you're displaying for `height` you're reading much more than that.

Answer (score 0):

The type long on gcc 64 bit is 64 bits long, but the original structure uses LONG, defined as 32 bit integers on Windows:

```
#pragma pack(push,1)
typedef struct tagBITMAPINFOHEADER {
  DWORD biSize; // use uint32_t instead
  LONG  biWidth;  // use int32_t instead
  LONG  biHeight; // use int32_t instead
  WORD  biPlanes;  // use uint16_t instead
  WORD  biBitCount;  // use uint16_t instead
  DWORD biCompression;  // use uint32_t instead
  DWORD biSizeImage;  // use uint32_t instead
  LONG  biXPelsPerMeter;  // use int32_t instead
  LONG  biYPelsPerMeter;  // use int32_t instead
  DWORD biClrUsed;  // use uint32_t instead
  DWORD biClrImportant;  // use uint32_t instead
} BITMAPINFOHEADER, *PBITMAPINFOHEADER;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Also, be aware of negative height values: this identify an image where the first scan row is at the top of the image (you have to get a labs() of the height)
Positive height values identify an image where the first scan row is at the bottom of the image.